Aws elastic ip reachability check
I wanna make elastic ip search(for my location) desktop app in electronjs. I can handle allocation, disallocation stuff with aws-sdk package. But main problem for me pinging or reachability check for elastic ip. I need to ping without connecting to an instance.
I tried net package but still I couldn't get response. Is it possible in nodejs. What can i do? Any methods will be helpful but I shouldn't connect elastic ip with an instance. I saw that it is possible, I have one desktop app for pinging and have project in python(but couldn't understand) that pings or checks reachability for my location.

So your question is 'how do I send a ping with a node.js'? Or is it something else. What have you tried so far. Why / how did that fail. This question lacks details.

What do you mean by "I saw that it is possible"?
